# Concatenate Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe

I am trying to concatenate few dataframes which depends on if they are created in the process. So for example I have following master list of many data frame

```
 List=['df_facebook','df_LinkedIn','df_Insta','tweet_final','df_Google','df_Slide','df_Youtube']
```

Now In my process, assume df_google did not get created, so I wont be able to do

```
df_Social = pd.concat([df_facebook,df_LinkedIn,df_Insta,tweet_final,df_Youtube,df_Google,df_Slide])
```

So to handle this, since I want it to completely automated & Dynamic, I tried to something like this

```
list_a=[col for col in List if col in locals()]
df_Social=pd.concat(list_a)
```

Which gives me an error

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object
```

Which is right also, Please help me to fix this, or some alternate solution, which can help me to just concatenate the already created dataframes dynamically. I will appreciate every help!

Comment: Youu need concanecate list of dataframes - so if use `list_a=[df_facebook,df_LinkedIn,df_Insta,...]`, then it works nice `df_Social=pd.concat(list_a)`.

Comment: And list can be filled dynamically.

Comment: In this solution the problem is List=[df_facebook,df_LinkedIn,df_Insta,tweet_final,df_Google,df_Slide...] won't work because df_Google wasn't created

Comment: your list comprehension is just getting the name of the DataFrame, which is a string.

Comment: @PhilChang- Thats the problem, string wont work for pd.concat & can't create a master list without string because one of the variables is not created in that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not a good idea to look variables in locals.
however, you can try:

```
list_a=[locals()[col] for col in List if col in locals()]
# for example
List = ['df_google', 'df_facebook', 'df_linkedin']
# the frames should have the same column name if you want to concat vertically
df_google = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(20,3))
df_facebook = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(40, 3))
list_a=[locals()[col] for col in List if col in locals()]
pd.concat(list_a)
```

Comment: Hmm, do you test it with samples of DataFrames?

Comment: yes, I tested. however if none of the dataframe was created, it will result an error.

Comment: Hmmm, I am not sure if i explain it in comment clearly. Do you understand me?

Comment: yes, I think I understood your idea. I created a list of names, and created some dataframes with that name. then use list comprehension to get the dataframe in the locals(), which is a dictionary.

Comment: My english is pure, maybe you can try explain it better. ;)

Comment: It is working but, cant convert it into a pd.Dataframe, result are coming absurd